# Multiple same dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, ajax

I'm able to create dynamic dropdown list using php,ajax,mysql. In this, second dropdown list (itemname) is populated upon selection of first dropdown list (itemtype).

I want to manage multiple items and therefore need same dropdown list (1st & 2nd) multiple times. For example,

1. Itemtype (dropdown list)  -> itemname (dropdown list) -> qty (input field)
2. Itemtype (dropdown list)  -> itemname (dropdown list) -> qty (input field)
3. Itemtype (dropdown list)  -> itemname (dropdown list) -> qty (input field)
4. Itemtype (dropdown list)  -> itemname (dropdown list) -> qty (input field)

ajax code is:

```
    $('#itemtype').on("change", function(){
 var itemtype = $('#itemtype').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_itemname.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {itemtype:itemtype},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){
                var len = response.length;
                $("#itemname").empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var itemname = response[i]['itemname'];
                    $("#itemname").append("<option value='"+itemname+"'>"+itemname+"</option>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

and html code:

```
Item Type:<select name="itemtype" id="itemtype" type="text">
<option value="">Select Type</option>
<?php
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT itemtype FROM products group by itemtype");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
$itemtype = $row['itemtype'];
echo "<option>$itemtype</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please update your question with real code, current output and expected output.

Comment: you need to expose your piece of code, but in theory, it is the same. For the second dropdown you query: `select itemnames from t where itemtype=i1` you make this upon the [select event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) with an AJAX call.